# Nginx map directive to specify redirection along with redirection type

Tags: nginx, redirection

I got redirections working by writing this config file:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default https://github.com;
    /www http://wow.com;
    /?p=1 http://wow.com/p1;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com;

    location / {
        if ($new_uri) {
            return 301 $new_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would also like to control whether its a 301 or 302 with each redirection, so I tried doing this:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default https://github.com;
    /www http://wow.com;
    /?p=1 http://wow.com/p1;
}
map $request_uri $ret_code {
    default 302;
    /www 302;
    /?p=1 302;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com;

    location / {
        if ($new_uri) {
            return $ret_code $new_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get the return statement right, it complains of `invalid return code` when I test the config file. How do I go about specifying the last line if I have both the return code and the url in variables?

Also, any pointers on how can I configure default to be:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default https://github.com$request_uri;
```

so that default redirection rule is set as `testdomain.com/whatever` to `github.com/whatever`?

Comment: The third redirect won't work, because nginx `$request_uri` does not contain query arguments.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Its actually working. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri

Comment: Do you really see the `Location: http://wow.com/p1` in the HTTP headers when you request `/?p=1`?

Comment: Yep! `$ curl -I testdomain.com/?p=1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2017 09:42:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://wow.com/p1
ret-code: 302`

Comment: My mistake, it was a different case where query arguments are not visible.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen No worries! An insights on the question? Seems like I am stuck cuz of syntax, should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using multiple `ifs`:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default DEFAULT;
    /www http://wow.com;
    /?p=1 http://wow.com/p1;
}
map $request_uri $ret_code {
    default 507;
    /www 302;
    /?p=1 301;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com;

    location / {
        if ($new_uri = 'DEFAULT') {
                return 301 https://github.com$request_uri;
        }

        if ($ret_code = 301) {
            return 301 $new_uri;
        }

        if ($ret_code = 302) {
                return 302 $new_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

I will leave the question unaccepted for a while to see if there any any pitfalls with it and there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to implement the status code.

For the default option, you can try this:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default DEFAULT;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com;

    location / {
        if ($new_uri = "DEFAULT") {
            return $ret_code https://github.com$request_uri;
        }
        if ($new_uri) {
            return $ret_code $new_uri;
        }
    }
}
```